# Why do I not get DragItemsCompleted and DragItemsStarting events when CanReorderItems is set to true on a UWP ListView?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, windows-runtime

I have a UWP XAML `<ListView>` that I want users to rearrange via drag and drop. [The `CanReorderItems` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems?view=winrt-19041) on ListViewBase provides that functionality and only requires a few properties:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    AllowDrop="True"
    DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting"
    DragItemsCompleted="ListView_DragItemsCompleted">
    <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

This successfully lets me drag and drop items within the ListView and fires `CollectionChanged` events on the `ItemsSource` (Remove then Add). However, it does not fire the `DragItemsStarting` and `DragItemsCompleted` events.

These events let me handle dragging atomically, rather than relying on two `CollectionChanged` events from the `ItemsSource`.

How do I get these events to fire?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView`s do not fire `DragItemsStarting` and `DragItemsCompleted` events unless [`CanDragItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.candragitems?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_CanDragItems) is set to true on the ListView:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
    CanDragItems="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    AllowDrop="True"
    DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting"
    DragItemsCompleted="ListView_DragItemsCompleted">
    <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

Once you add this property, you should find that these events will fire.